# how to pass id on click event

Tags: typescript, angular2-forms

Here i have simple table Like

```
<table class="table table-striped">                
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th class="pointer" (click)="sort($event.target.value.Id)">Auction ID</th></tr>
<tbody>
         <tr *ngFor="let value of pagedItems">
                      <td>{{value.Id}}</td>
```

This is my code

```
     sort(property){
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to access the id value from the pagedItems you are iterating over, or another id value?

Comment: @MarkReimer im trying to access the id value from the page

Comment: @JpDuminy, are **$event.target.value.Id** and **value.Id** are same? Please be specific

Comment: @JayakrishnanGounder do u have any idea to pass this id from <Th> to typescript code

Comment: @JpDuminy, the question still remains the same, which id? you are telling **this id from <th>**. But <th> element has no id

Comment: @JayakrishnanGounder  could u plz reffer this Url     http://www.advancesharp.com/blog/1211/angular-2-search-and-sort-with-ngfor-repeater-with-example        Here im trying to do sorting

Comment: @JpDuminy, I checked and it accepts the column name in string on which sorting is to be applied. eg: sort('CategoryID') and they are using it to access the property in the list in your case it will be pagedItems. So you just need to pass sort('Id')

Comment: @JayakrishnanGounder  Thank u soo much for ur valueable time and idea